# Trying to me make sense of what I get from Rate and Increase functions in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I am trying to get a count of the 5m total HTTP messages to/from my application and after reading in several articles (including similar discussions on this site), I gathered I should be using the "increase" function.
My traffic runs in the following pattern:
20 msg per sec for 30sec every 2 mins. So theoretically if I start at min=0 total traffic in 5m should be 1800msgs. But since increase is really rate time secs. I get fluctuating values. Now using rate for 1min range, I get a curve that fluctuates from 0 to 12 in a span of 1.5min (see picture) with 15sec steps. If I use "rate" with a 5m range, the curve is flattened even more.
This in itself not sure how to interpret.
Then I use "increase" to count the total 5min, and that curve fluctuates between ~1240 to ~1865. (see pictures attached).
My questions:

1. What to make out of the rate function, which value should I consider as my per sec? as obviously 12, is not even close to 20.
2. What should I make from the increase that fluctuates like that? which value should I pick? I guess 1865 is more realistic to my traffic pattern, but that changes based on when I query the result from a client, but that makes it an instant query doesn't it? I am not sure this is a 5min count though...
3. Lastly isn't it that a counter always goes up (except for reset), so why am I seeing picks and troughs?

My scraping interval is 10sec.

Request pattern:

[image: request pattern]

5m increase count:

[image: 5m Increase count]

1m rate display:

[image: 1min rate display]

Answer (score 0):

1. The "Rate" function calculates the per-second average rate. In the pick you have 20 msgs per sec, but only for 30s, so in an average, you have about 10 msgs per sec in 1m, due to the lack of messages in the others 30s. The 12 value is correct.
2. The "Increase" function calculates how much the counter is increasing in the time range (5m). This value fluctuates according to the 5m windows catches the 30s picks or not. In the best case, it catches 3 picks x 20 msgs x 30s = 1800 (the highest point of the graphic), in the worst case, it catches only 2 picks x 20 msgs x 30s = 1200 (the lowest point of the graphic).
3. Correct, the counter always goes up, but sometimes the counter is increasing fast and other times it's increasing slow. The "Increase" function is here just to show how much the counter is increasing at each moment. Remember that the "Increase" is calculated in the time range (5m in your case).